# How using sed on AIX differs from using it on linux

Tags: linux, regex, sed, aix

I know that `-i` option doesn't exist in sed for AIX but recently I've bumped into a different issue when trying to edit the /etc/services file in AIX.

I need to replace a line from this file so for example instead of this line:

```
nimhttp         4901/udp
```

I should have this one:

```
nimhttp         5001/tcp
```

On linux I could just use this barberian command:

```
sed 's/nimhttp         4901\/udp/nimhttp         5001\/tcp/g' /etc/services > /etc/services.tmp
```

Or maybe I could be little bit smarter and use this one:

```
sed 's/^nimhttp\s\{3,\}4901\/udp/nimhttp\s\{9\}5001\/tcp/g' /etc/services > /etc/services.tmp
```

And still end up with my .tmp file being edited as needed.

On AIX none of those (and many other more) commands I've tried do not work. Tried to figure out what are the differences between them but as **sed** is itself a complex command, I cannot.

So my question is, does anyone know why this doesn't work on AIX or can I find a list of differences between the two versions of the sed command found on both systems?

The linux sed command version is 4.2.2 and AIX's is unknown as `sed --version` doesn't work either nor is there a mention in sed's man page about finding the version but I assume it's also the latest as I'm on AIX 7.2

Comment: Is a Perl one-liner an option for you?

Comment: Have a try with `perl -ape 's~^nimhttp\h+\K4901/udp~5001/tcp~' /etc/services > /etc/services.tmp`

Comment: @Toto No, perl or python is not an option either - AIX is very strict when it comes to installed packages and if it doesn't really need it, it does not have it or allow to install it so I have to deal with what I have. Even if there are alternatives, I would really love to find out how to do it with sed as it's not the first time I bumped into using sed on AIX.

Comment: Nothing works, what isn't in POSIX standard. That means GNU extension doesn't work in AIX!sed.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond So you are saying I cannot do a simple search/replace using sed in AIX?

Comment: Your first command does work with AIX!sed, the second one can be modifed into this: `sed 's/^nimhttp *4901\/udp/nimhttp         5001\/tcp/g' /etc/services >/etc/services.tmp` (mind you, you can use other separator character not only slash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Lorinczy Zsigmond, Linux versions of `sed` implements a lot of `GNU Extensions` to ease its use.

To test under Linux, use `sed --posix` (and welcome to the old Unix world ;-p)

To the job you want to achieve in "posix" mode, the following two commands works:

```
/tmp/test$ cat test_file
nimhttp         4901/udp
/tmp/test$ sed --posix -e 's/4901\/udp/5001\/tcp/g' test_file 
nimhttp         5001/tcp
/tmp/test$ sed --posix -e 's#4901/udp#5001/tcp#g' test_file 
nimhttp         5001/tcp
```

If you want to also match on the service name:

```
/tmp/test$ cat test_file
nimhttp         4901/udp
nimnothttp      104901/udp
/tmp/test$ sed --posix -e 's#\(nimhttp.*\)4901/udp#\15001/tcp#g' test_file 
nimhttp         5001/tcp
nimnothttp      104901/udp
```

Note that `\( \)` is for memorizing matched pattern. Then you recall the memorized pattern witn `\1` (or `\2`, `\3` etc... depending on the number of memorized patterns).

Maybe the command you used to use won't work ... but like with Perl, there's always several ways to do the same things with `sed`.

Comment: So on short, what I'm trying to accomplish isn't possible on AIX using sed? I'm forced to reinforce this question both because I'm amazed to find this and to understand if this answer of yours should be regarded as an accepted answer.

Comment: Answer edited...

Comment: Thank you for your updates but the commands that you have provided don't include the service itself eg. nimhttp so if another service is using the same port or part of that port eg 0005491 I will end up replacing its configuration (port # and protocol) and I don't want that.

Comment: updated, again ;-)

Comment: Awesome, I got it working. Please note that `-e` flag is unnecessary here. From sed man page: `If you are using just one -e flag and no -f flag, the -e flag can be omitted.`